# Using println can't get the right output format

Tags: java

how do i change this number: `5.8774367E-7` to `0.00000058774367` ?
thanks a lot.
the code:

```
float Deal_order = Deal_factor*(float)Order_value;
System.out.println("Deal Order is:" + Deal_order);
```

anther question:
how do i do the same in a GUI?

textField_9.setText(Float.toString(Deal_factor));

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried to use printf instead of println?

Answer (score 5):

Use `printf()`

```
System.out.printf("Deal Order is: %.14f\n", Deal_order);
```

The part after the dot (14 in this example) is how many decimal places your number will have.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using 'println',  You can easily format output with 'printf' as

```
System.out.printf("Deal order is: %.15f\n", Deal_order );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` to set format.

Try:

```
System.out.printf("Deal order is: %.10f\n", Deal_order);
```

In terms of large decimals digits, you can search about `BigDecimal`.